# Excel inetrop Graph printing

Tags: c#, excel, printing, graph

I am printing a chart using excel inter OP in c#. The values are filled in the excel sheet and the graph is plot based on that. Every thing is working fine. when I am printing the graph, there is a problem in that[image: Graph plot] The axis values are repeated. What will be a solution?

Comment: Looks like you have twice as many tick marks as you need, and the number format for your axis labels set to only whole numbers (making 0.5 show up as 1.0). Please include code if you want someone to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It can easily done in excel by "format axis" option.

[image: Axis format Dialog]